# How to hide content that is not wrapped by tag using only CSS?

Tags: html, css, hide

I have the following html:

```
<a href="..."><span>ICON</span>Text</a>
```

How can I remove only the "Text" using CSS rules?
NOTE: I need to continue to see the  content.

Comment: Enclose this tag with a div and then "play" with the visibility options of the div element!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on Paulie_D's answer, I came with a solution by using `font-size`:

```
a {
    font-size: 0;
}

a span {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/32mujnkf/3/)

Based on the comments on this answer, I think this might be the solution. It isn't perfect, but will do. We use my answer with the `font-size: 0`. Like Paulie_D commented this won't work crossbrowser, some browser will show it in a font-size of 4px. For those browser we add Paulie_D's solution too:

```
a {
    font-size: 0;
    visibility:hidden;
}

a span {
    font-size: 16px;
    visibility:visible;
}
```

To see the difference between the two: [check here](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/32mujnkf/4/).

Comment: Nice but may not work in some browsers where min-font size is 4px. All solutions have problems. :) Frankly, I'd use a second span and `display:none` it.

Comment: I agree on the second span!

Comment: I can't change the HTML :(

Answer (score 6):

You can use `visibility` for this

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/32mujnkf/)

**CSS**

```
a {
    visibility:hidden;
}

a span {
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Comment: Nice solution! But it should be noted that when using it inline, the place is 'reserved', check [the updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/32mujnkf/2/).